# Override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid

Tags: adminhtml, overrides, sales-order, order-grid, configuration

I'm trying to override the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` class, but no success with that.

My `config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AD_Tweaks>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </AD_Tweaks>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product>AD_Tweaks_Catalog_Model_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
             </catalog>
         </models>
         <blocks>
             <catalog>
                 <rewrite>
                     <layer_filter_attribute>AD_Tweaks_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute</layer_filter_attribute>
                     <layer_filter_price>AD_Tweaks_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price</layer_filter_price>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>AD_Tweaks_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                    <sales_order_create_form_account>AD_Tweaks_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Account</sales_order_create_form_account>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
         </blocks>
     </global>
</config>
```

My overriding PHP File located on `/app/code/local/AD/Tweaks/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`:

```
    <?php
    class AD_Tweaks_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            // ***This function should be executed, but it fails***
            Mage::log('Class ' . get_class($this) . ' is being created');
            parent::__construct();
        }
}
```

I tried even to put a `Mage::log('1111');` statement on top of the overriding class (before the `class` operator), but it probably doesn't loads my PHP file because there is no `1111` shown in logs.

The error is displayed in the browser is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object in  /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php on line 66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem just by changing the files permissions to `www-data` instead of `root`.

Comment: I am also facing same problem not abel to override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Grid

Comment: @AnishaShaikh, have you tried to do this by placing to the config.xml file  `<global><blocks><adminhtml><rewrite><permissions_user_grid>Your_Module_Block_Permissions_User_Grid</permissions_user_grid></rewrite></adminhtml></blocks></global>`

Answer (score 3):

You Rewrite   grid file location is wrong

```
/app/code/local/AD/Tweaks/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

should be

```
/app/code/local/AD/Tweaks/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

Also need to chnage in classs

```
AD_Tweaks_Block_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
```

**Also**

```
<sales_order_grid>AD_Tweaks_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
```

change

```
<sales_order_grid>AD_Tweaks_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
```

Comment: Are you sure it should be `AD_Tweaks_Block_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` with double `Block` word?

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't work. Also are sure that Adminhtml and Block should be swapped? Notice that I'm trying to override `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` — so look to the placement of these words.